# SQL Server 2012 CONTAINSTABLE appears case-sensitive in isolated instance

Tags: sql-server-2012

Version: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5532.0 (X64) Ju (...)

My table, `TableToSearch`, contains a full-text index on multiple columns with "Language for Word Break" as "Neutral" for each column (English will not serve my purposes -- period acts as a word break).

Multiple records contain the phrase "John Q. Adams". However, if the "Q" is lower-case in the search phrase, `CONTAINSTABLE` finds nothing. It seems to have something to do with the period.

E.g.:

```
CONTAINSTABLE (TableToSearch, *, @SearchTerms)
```

`@SearchTerms` finds records containing "John Q. Adams" in these instances:

```
SET @SearchTerms = '"John Q. Adams"'
SET @SearchTerms = '"john Q. Adams"'
SET @SearchTerms = '"John Q. adams"'
SET @SearchTerms = '"john Q. adams"'
```

`@SearchTerms` finds nothing in these instances:

```
SET @SearchTerms = '"John q. Adams"'
SET @SearchTerms = '"john q. Adams"'
SET @SearchTerms = '"John q. adams"'
SET @SearchTerms = '"john q. adams"'
```

I appreciate any insights anyone has on this behavior.

Comment: Does `CONTAINS` give ssame results? Are your columns `NVARCAHR`? Is `@SearchTerms` - `NVARCHAR`? Try `SET @SearchTerms = N'"John q. Adams"'`

Comment: What is collation of columns used for full-text index? What is DB/table collation?

Comment: What is you full text index language?

Comment: Check that `'q'` is not in the stopword list.